# IdentityServer.IdentityManager requires no login

Tags: identityserver3, identitymanager

I am using the AspNetIdentity sample from the IdentityServer3 Samples file. When I start up the application the first page shows links for the Identity Server Welcome page and the Identity Manager User admin. When I click on the Identity manager admin link it automatically logs into the server and you can create, update etc any users, roles etc. How can this be modified to require a login? It seems obvious to me that this should not automatically log in and allow this access - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity Manager's default security is "Local Host" security. This means the caller/user is considered trusted if that caller is browsing from the same machine that is hosting Identity Manager. This is just the default, other security modes are available. Brock has a [good video](https://vimeo.com/125427106) that explains the other modes.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a great deal!